# Perl regular expression letter.number

Tags: regex, perl

Perl

I have strings:

xxxx.log, log.1, log.2, blog, photolog

So I would like to match only the strings named

1. [log.num]  e.g  log.1 log.12 log.3
2. [.log] e.g  xxxx.log

not include the string named blog, phtotlog.

any helps would be appreciated.

So far this is my code but i will match blog and some words have "log" that is not i want.

```
while( <> ) {
        printf "%s",$_ if /log/;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want `/\blog\b/` aka `/(?<!\w)log(?!\w)/`?

Comment: @ikegami it works good!! could you please explain this pattern? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained, `\blog\b` may work for your data.  However, if `log` can come in the string along yet other non-word characters (like `log-a.txt`) that gets matched, too, so you need be more specific.  One way is to match precisely what is expected. By the shown sample

```
while (<>) {
    print if /(?: \.log | log\.\d+ )$/x;
}
```

where `(?: )` is the *non capturing* group, used so that either of the alternation patterns is anchored to the end of the string, `$` (but not needlessly captured). Otherwise we'd match `x.log.OLD` or such.  With the `/x` modifier spaces may be used without being matched, good for readability.

The patterns in alternation `|` can be combined but that gets far more complicated.

The `printf %s, $var` has no advantage over `print $var` (unless the format is more involved).

A one-liner test

```
perl -wE'
   @ary = qw(log-out xxxx.log log.1 log.2 blog photolog);
   /(?:\.log|log\.\d+)$/ && say for @ary
'
```

where [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) `say` is used for the newline, needed here. In a one-liner `-E` (capital) enables it.

Comment: @Luke  The `/x` is not necessary by any means -- I used it in text to make it easier to look at the regex, but in one-liner I don't so that there's less typing and is more compact.  In scripts and production code one often sees `/x` specially when the regex is more complex.  One-liners are mostly used to try things out, and `/x` may make them longer and unwiedly.  All matter of taste.

Comment: @Luke  You are most welcome :).  Let me know if more explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @zdim it is very helpful :)

Comment: @Luke  great :)  I mean let me know if I should add more (and what), and if things come up

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
while( <> ) {
        printf "%s",$_ if /\blog\b/;
}
```

The key being the \b that's a word boundary.  You can read about them here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html  but pretty much it's a space, non letter, the beginning of the line, or end of the line.  Another option would be:

```
/\.log\d/
```

That would match .log3  The period has to be escaped and the \d means a number.  That being said I think \b is what you want.

Comment: so it only matches the word between \b WORD \b right?

Comment: yep, \b is a zero width match.  I think _ does count as part of the word though, but usually using \b is going to do exactly what is being looked for.

Comment: I just tried \bWORD and \bWORD\b, the results are the same. So, what is the difference between     \bWORD     and     \bWORD\b

Comment: Give this a read:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html   the \b  is a zero width match with special meanings.  :)